# Putting in random order

Tags: java

so for school i have to make a password generator in which we can set the amount of passwords as well as the amount of lower case letters, upper case letters, symbols and numbers. Here's the code:

```
package vantroys;

import java.util.Random;

public class PasswordGeneratorTest {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {

    int lowerCase;
    int randomNum;
    Random rand = new Random();



    SimpleInOutDialog num = new SimpleInOutDialog("randomgenerator");
    PasswordGeneratorClass test = new PasswordGeneratorClass();


    test.setAmountPasswords(num.readInteger("How many passwords do you want to generate?"));









    while (test.getAmountPasswords()>0){
        test.setAmountLetters(num.readInteger("How many letters should this password contain?"));
        test.setAmountUpperCase(num.readInteger("How many of these letters should be upper case?"));

        if (test.getAmountUpperCase()>test.getAmountLetters()){
            num.showString("", "This isn't possible, there aren't enough letters.");
            num.stop();
        }

        test.setAmountNumbers(num.readInteger("How many numbers should the password contain?"));
        test.setAmountSymbols(num.readInteger("How many symbols should the password contain?"));

        lowercase= test.getAmountLetters()-test.getAmountUpperCase();

        while (lowercase>0){
            char a = (char) (rand.nextInt(26) + 'a');
            lowercase=lowercase-1;

        }

        while (test.getAmountUpperCase()>0){
            char b = (char) (rand.nextInt(26) + 'A');
            test.setAmountUpperCase(test.getAmountUpperCase()-1);
        }

        while (test.getAmountNumbers()>0){
            randomNum = rand.nextInt((10 - 1) + 1) + 1;
            System.out.println(randomNum);
            test.setAmountNumbers(test.getAmountNumbers()-1);
        }

        while (test.getAmountSymbols()>0){
            char c = (char) (rand.nextInt(0xB4 - 21 + 1) + 21);
            System.out.println(c);
            test.setAmountSymbols(test.getAmountSymbols()-1);
        }
        test.setAmountPasswords(test.getAmountPasswords()-1);
    }
}
```

everything works but now i'm supposed to put all of the letters, numbers and symbols i generated in a random order and i can't figure out how to do it, is there an easy way to do this that i'm just not seeing?

Comment: This sounds like a request for a homework or project solution. As a community on stack overflow we are here to help with a specific programming issue if you have attempted the problem and show the steps that you have taken. We aren't here to solve your homework or code your projects. Please use the resources in your course to at least come up with an attempt first then come back and request help.

Answer (score 0):

Put all chars in a list. Then use [Collections.shuffle()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Random%29)